# How to invoke Google Assistant via Button

Tags: actions-on-google, google-assist-api

all:
We want to enable Google Assistant with custom actions via the button, not the voice input (keyword).
For example, usually, we enable Google Assistant with word "Hello, Google, show me the weather.". But within our production, we want to press one specific button, and then it could send the sentence above out to Google Assistant directly.

But we can't find any APIs to support this requirement. And we heard that Google plan to support hard-key method since Samsung make good experiences on S8
Do anyone help us to fix this gap?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You could use an [Action link](https://developers.google.com/assistant/engagement/action-links#action_link_parameters) without any additional parameters specified to trigger the MAIN intent, or specify the custom intent you'd like to trigger.